# Ubuntu 19.10 shows black screen with 99 letter combination

Tags: 19.10

My ubuntu 19.10 is now showing a black screen with 99 letter combination.It appears after booting the machine
Any one who can help on how to resolve this.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was as a result of Grub which was lost. After booting the machine using a LIVE Ubuntu CD, **Boot repair** fixed the issue